# How to clean up downloaded files in Django view testing?

Tags: python, django, testing, automated-tests

I have a Django view that returns a file to download (`response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + filename`) in response to a POST as the contents of the file are dependent on data submitted by a form. In setting up my tests for this view, I'm having a hard time finding a clean way to download the file and make sure it is cleaned up afterwards as this doesn't come for free with the TestCase behavior. Currently I have the following:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir='.') as temp_dir:
    os.chdir(temp_dir)
    response = self.client.post(...)
    # Do asserts of the downloaded file/response object here
    os.chdir('..')
```

This has the benefit of creating a temporary directory where the file is downloaded to, and the whole directory is deleted when the test completes. Also, if any of the asserts fail the temp directory (and contents) will stick around, but this specifically feels fragile and like it could break other tests because of the directory change.

Is there a better way/pattern to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using TestCase, I think that your filename for this test has a fixed name. TestCase came with two methods (setUp and tearDown) to help you do things before and after every test.

setUp > test_first_test > tearDown

setUp > test_second_test > tearDown

and so on

```
class Mytests(TestCase):

    def test_first_test(self): 
        your definition here

    def test_second_test(self): 
        your definition here

    def tearDown(self):
        os.system('rm -rf ./mytestfile.extension') # command for linux
```

Comment: Correct, my filename is fixed in the context of the test, and this solution would definitely work. It felt a little wrong though because the file is being created/deleted in a directory alongside other files in my project, and using tempfile.TemporaryDirectory at least provided a tiny bit of isolation for that.